# Regex for alphanumeric and space in between

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I have below Patterns

```
var initalValue = '#1223sdf#4f43      S DSD3rdsf'
console.log(initalValue.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\s?]*/g, ''));
console.log(initalValue.replace(/^([^a-zA-Z0-9])*/g, ''));
console.log(initalValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]*[^a-zA-Z0-9][\s+]*/g, ''));
```

What I am trying it should start with alphanumeric only and have single space in between words, but none of above working.

Here is the directive I tried using with the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57707948/3832970), it still does not allow whitespace inside a string:

```
   export class NoSpecialCharacterOrSpaceAtStart {

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;
    //[^0-9]*
    console.log(initalValue)

    this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/^[^A-Z0-9]+|[^A-Z0-9]+$|([^A-Z0-9]+)/gi, function (_, $1) {
      return $1 ? " " : "";
    });
    console.log(this._el.nativeElement.value)
    if (initalValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please post the desired output

Comment: If you add a working plunkr/codepen to showcase the issue it would be helpful to debug the issue. In some cases, when preparing a plunkr, you can detect the issue yourself since it may be a simple code issue not related to the current issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to remove non-alphanumeric from start/end and replace all 1+ non-alphanumeric inside the string with a single space.

You may use

```js
var initalValue = '#1223sdf#4f43      S DSD3rdsf';
console.log(initalValue.replace(/^[^A-Z0-9]+|[^A-Z0-9]+$|([^A-Z0-9]+)/gi, function(_, $1) {
  return $1 ? " " : "";
}))
```

**Details**

- `^[^A-Z0-9]+` - 1+ non-alphanumeric chars at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `[^A-Z0-9]+$` - 1+ non-alphanumeric chars at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `([^A-Z0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1: 1+ non-alphanumeric chars inside the string
- `$1 ? " " : ""` - if Group 1 matched, replace with a space, else, remove the match.

Comment: This is not allowin space in between

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Do you see the `1223sdf 4f43 S DSD3rdsf` output? Isn't it expected? Please explain what you mean by "allowin space in between".

Comment: Actually I am implementing this in directive, but it is not working

Comment: I know this is diff, I have updated the post, could be please check once

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Are you sure there are no additional directives added here? Like [this one](https://gist.github.com/jokecamp/d7dadd5474b79b90d623a8ba8fe7f919).

Comment: Yes, only this directive added

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam At any rate, this solution of mine is working. You just need to implement it appropriately in your code.